# SQL Server Pivot - distinct values

Tags: sql-server

I would like to pivot table a sum of sales in SQL Server.

My table is slightly more complicated than what is below, but this is a good example:

[image]

The Pivot I am after should look something like this:

[image]

Obviously this is quite straightforward using MS Excel, however, since my data is ridiculously huge, it is housed at a table in SQL Server. Therefore, I am needing write an query to pivot table as example above.

What I have written is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Day] FROM [TABLE]
PIVOT (SUM(Cost) FOR [Prod] IN([Coke], [Pepsi], [Tango])) AS PIVOTSALES
```

However, I am failing to get the required result. Any advise how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, you would only have to add the pivoted fields to your SELECT list (and remove that DISTINCT, because the data is grouped automatically):

```
SELECT [Day], [Coke], [Pepsi], [Tango]
FROM [TABLE]
PIVOT (SUM([Cost]) FOR [Prod] IN ([Coke], [Pepsi], [Tango])) AS PIVOTSALES
```

**But...**

I hope that your table also has a primary key, and if so, this query will not work, since PIVOT not only creates columns for the values of the pivoted field (`Prod`) that will contain values calculated using the value field (`Cost`) but also does a `GROUP BY` by all other columns contained in what is specified in the FROM clause. Therefore, if your table contains more than the mentionned 3 columns `Day`, `Prod` and `Cost`, you will have to specify a subquery in the FROM clause (and give it an alias):

```
SELECT [Day], [Coke], [Pepsi], [Tango]
FROM (SELECT [Day], [Cost], [Prod] FROM [TABLE]) AS [Alias]
PIVOT (SUM([Cost]) FOR [Prod] IN ([Coke], [Pepsi], [Tango])) AS PIVOTSALES
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only selecting `Day`.   You need to add the other columns to your SELECT list.

Compare your current query to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server).